# Access denied when trying to access USB HID device via pyusb

Tags: python, linux, usb, manjaro

I want to send data to a USB HID device with Python. Here's my script:

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

# Device constants
VENDOR_ID = 0x1b1c
PRODUCT_ID = 0x0a6b

# Find our device
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=VENDOR_ID, idProduct=PRODUCT_ID)

# Set the active configuration.
# With no arguments, the first configuration will be the active one
dev.set_configuration()
```

On the last line (set_configuration) I get the following error:

> usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)

I already created the following udev rule, but that did not help:

**99-corsair.py:**

```
# allow r/w access by all users
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1b1c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0a6b", MODE="0666"
```

The same error keeps coming up.
What else is necessary to allow USB-HID access via pyusb?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a device file in /dev/ that needs to belong to the right group and have rw permissions. You can accomplish that by inserting the following in a .rules file in for example filename /etc/udev/rules.d/myown.rules:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1b1c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0a6b", MODE="0660"
KERNEL=="your_device_name/*", MODE="0660", GROUP="your_group_name"
KERNEL=="your_device_name", MODE="0660", GROUP="your_group_name"
```

Just find out your_device_name in /dev and what name your_group_name is for that device and you will be ok to communicate with the USB HID device.

A more general investigation to find the problem with "usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)" is that libusb - that PyUSB uses - checks for permissions on two files. The two files (on a specific system Fedora 38) are located in /dev and /dev/bus/usb/. Do a 'lsusb' to find your device (bus number and device number - e.g bus 1 and device 5 in this example) and corresponds to /dev/bus/usb/001/005. Also check which file is corresponding to the device in /dev,  by plugging in and plugging out the device and do a 'ls -al /dev/' before and after pluigging in the device. Check the permissions on the two files before and after writing the udev rules and do a reboot after writing the udev rules. You should be ok now and should be able to communicate with the device as a normal user. Also your user needs to belong to the group as specified in the .rules file - check with 'groups'. You also need to reboot if you added yourself to a new group - you cannot just log in and log out in this case.

/BR Henrik